# Removing an XWPFParagraph keeps the paragraph symbol (¶) for it

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to remove a set of contiguous paragraphs from a Microsoft Word document, using `Apache POI`.

From what I have understood, deleting a paragraph is possible by removing all of its runs, this way:

```
/*
 * Deletes the given paragraph.
 */
public static void deleteParagraph(XWPFParagraph p) {
    if (p != null) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        //Delete all the runs
        for (int i = runs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            p.removeRun(i);
        }
        p.setPageBreak(false); //Remove the eventual page break
    }
}
```

In fact, it works, but there's something strange. The block of removed paragraphs does not disappear from the document, but it's converted in a set of empty lines. It's just like every paragraph would be converted into a new line.

By printing the paragraphs' content from code I can see, in fact, a space (for each one removed). Looking at the content directly from the document, with the formatting mark's visualization enabled, I can see this:

[image]

The vertical column of ¶ corresponds to the block of deleted elements.

Do you have an idea for that? I'd like my paragraphs to be *completely* removed.

I also tried by replacing the text (with `setText()`) and by removing eventual spaces that could be added automatically, this way:

```
p.setSpacingAfter(0);
p.setSpacingAfterLines(0);
p.setSpacingBefore(0);
p.setSpacingBeforeLines(0);
p.setIndentFromLeft(0);
p.setIndentFromRight(0);
p.setIndentationFirstLine(0);
p.setIndentationLeft(0);
p.setIndentationRight(0);
```

But with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would delete paragraphs by deleting paragraphs, not by deleting only the runs in this paragraphs. Deleting paragraphs is not part of the `apache poi` high level API. But using `XWPFDocument.getDocument().getBody()` we can get the low level `CTBody` and there is a `removeP(int i)`.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Desktop;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

public class WordRemoveParagraph {

 /*
  * Deletes the given paragraph.
  */

 public static void deleteParagraph(XWPFParagraph p) {
  XWPFDocument doc = p.getDocument();
  int pPos = doc.getPosOfParagraph(p);
  //doc.getDocument().getBody().removeP(pPos);
  doc.removeBodyElement(pPos);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));

  int pNumber = doc.getParagraphs().size() -1;
  while (pNumber >= 0) {
   XWPFParagraph p = doc.getParagraphs().get(pNumber);
   if (p.getParagraphText().contains("delete")) {
    deleteParagraph(p);
   }
   pNumber--;
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

  System.out.println("Done");
  Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("result.docx"));

 }

}
```

This deletes all paragraphs from the document source.docx where the text contains "delete" and saves the result in result.docx.

---

Edited:

Although `doc.getDocument().getBody().removeP(pPos);` works, it will not update the `XWPFDocument`'s paragraphs list. So it will destroy paragraph iterators and other accesses to that list since the list is only updated while reading the document again.

So the better approach is using `doc.removeBodyElement(pPos);` instead. [removeBodyElement(int pos)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#removeBodyElement-int-) does exactly the same as `doc.getDocument().getBody().removeP(pos);` if the `pos` is pointing to a pagagraph in the document body since that paragraph is an `BodyElement` too. But in addition, it will update the `XWPFDocument`'s paragraphs list.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside of a table you need to use the functions of the `XWPFTableCell` instead of the `XWPFDocument`:

```
cell.removeParagraph(cell.getParagraphs().indexOf(para));
```