# Apache POI, XWPF: Remaining carriage return after removement

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

In my code I am successfully removing content from a paragraph, or its runs, to be more specific. This works, but after the removement there is still one carriage return left.

My plan was to remove a sentence from the Word document, and shifting the lower content up to the line, where to previous sentence was.

Additionally I wanted to avoid that a sentence is being split by ignoring the separation by runs. For this I take the whole text of the paragraph, transform it, set that text in the first run, and remove all following runs. But this seems to left me that annoying carriage return.

Here, a snippet of my code:

```
    String paragraphText = paragraph.getText();
    // The prefix and suffix are some simple substrings.
    String removement = prefix + deletionClause + suffix;

    paragraphText = paragraphText.replace(removement, "");

    paragraph.getRuns().get(0).setText(paragraphText,0);

    for(int j = 1; j < paragraph.getRuns().size(); j++)
    {
        paragraph.removeRun(j);
    }
```

There is the method `removeCarriageReturn()`, but I had no luck with that, yet. I am wondering if this carriage return does not belong to the paragraph, but trying to remove it by accessing the follower, just removed the text of the following paragraph, but still not that carriage return.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345285/removing-an-xwpfparagraph-keeps-the-paragraph-symbol-for-it/40347193#40347193

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But I found one issue in this approach. As soon as I am trying to reiterate through the paragraphs a second time, an exception will be thrown, because it is missing a link now, since the paragraph was deleted. Is there a way to close that gap by linking the previous and the next paragraph to each other?

Comment: Yes you are right. Although `doc.getDocument().getBody().removeP(pPos);` works, it will not update the `XWPFDocument`'s paragraphs list. So it will destroy paragraph iterators and other accesses to that list since the list is only updated while reading the document again. So the better approach is using `doc.removeBodyElement(pPos);` instead. See my editing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345285/removing-an-xwpfparagraph-keeps-the-paragraph-symbol-for-it/40347193#40347193.

Comment: You are right. I was so excited to try your solution that I didn't notice your edit. Thanks, I am pretty sure that may problem is solved with that.

Comment: I'm glad if I could help you. My edit was yesterday and was a reaction on your comment. So there was no chance for you to notice my edit before. Otherwise it would have been very strange ;-).