# How to delete a line from a Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Please do you know how to remove a line in MS Word using Apache POI?

I tried to remove the runs in the paragraph itself but no way.

Here's the code I tried:

```java
List<XWPFRun> runs = parag.getRuns();
for(int i = 0; i< runs.size(); i++) {
    parag.removeRun(i);
}
```

Comment: This should work and remove all the text runs from a given paragraph. So what exactly means "but no way"? Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Btw.: There is [XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#removeBodyElement-int-) to remove whole body elements (paragraphs for example).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345285/removing-an-xwpfparagraph-keeps-the-paragraph-symbol-for-it/40347193#40347193

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually when I use  XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement(int position) it throws a XmlValueDisconnectedException. What I want to do is to remove a line if it contains a specific name, ex {TO_REMOVE}

Comment: I have linked a complete example. This is tested and works. Note iteration the paragraphs from last to first and not using iterator, because if deleting while iterating from first to last, the iterator might get out of order. That's why the error.